# "SocketException: Name or service not known" when URL loads fine in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following code:

```
var url = "http://myComputer.myDomain.net:44344/Testing/TestCall";
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
var content = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

When I run this, I get the following exception thrown:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

With an inner exception of:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Name or service not known
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

There is additional call stack, but I don't see it as useful...

The really odd thing is that if I take the URL (`http://myComputer.myDomain.net:44344/Testing/TestCall`) and put it in a browser, it runs the call on my service just fine and returns the expected output.

**Why would I get a "Name or service not known" exception, but have the same URL work fine in the browser?**

Additional Information:  If I replace the url with `"http://google.com"`, then it works fine.  Which makes me think it is my service.  But the service loads fine from the browser....   I am very confused.

Comment: can you add your `Startup.cs` code + make sure you have `System.Net.Http` imported or downloaded

Comment: @Kardon63 - It works just fine for the url `http://google.com`.  So it must be something in my service...  Odd that it loads just fine from the browser though.

Comment: This sounds more likely to be an environmental issue.    What happens if you try `System.Net.Ping` to `myComputer.myDomain.net`  instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forgot that, because I am using docker containers, I cannot have one container address another container using the hostname and port number.

When I replaced `myComputer.myDomain.net:44344` with the hostname of the container found in my docker file it all started working.

Comment: I have the same issue, the difference is I can't access "https://login.microsoftonline.com/568173fa-1eb8-4608-b9bd-36714706d7c6/oauth2/token" from within my .net core 3.1 running in docker. What could be a solution, do you have any idea?